# sessionStorage value becomes null in other tab in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, session-storage

After Login I stored the value in session in Angular:

```
sessionStorage.setItem("CustomerID", JSON.stringify(CustomerID));
sessionStorage.setItem("Email", JSON.stringify(email));
```

Here I am fetching the session value:

```
var sessionvalue = sessionStorage.getItem("CustomerID");
```

In the other tab if I open the page then the `sessionvalue` becomes `null`.
It works for the same tab.

Why does it become `null` in the other tab the browser?

Comment: Session is particular to a single window or tab. Opening a new tab will instantiate a new session: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage

Comment: In Login how can i store a session which is accesible globally in whole over the project of angular webapi till logout or can be like session time 2 minute

Comment: You may need to look into other storage mechanisms such as Session Storage, Cookies or WebSQL to put out a few.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to **MDN**

> The sessionStorage property allows you to access a session Storage object for the current origin. sessionStorage is similar to Window.localStorage, the only difference is while data stored in localStorage has no expiration set, data stored in sessionStorage gets cleared when the page session ends. A page session lasts for as long as the browser is open and survives over page reloads and restores. Opening a page in a new tab or window will cause a new session to be initiated, which differs from how session cookies work.

**Source:** [Window.sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)

---

So you may need something else like [window.localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

***Example:***

```js
// in a-page.html
localStorage.setItem("CustomerID", JSON.stringify(CustomerID));

// in b-page.html
var CustomerID =  localStorage.getItem("CustomerID", JSON.parse(CustomerID));
```

Comment: In Login how can i store a session which is accesible globally in whole over the project of angular webapi till logout or can be like session time 20 minute..Is there any way ??

Comment: @asasasaa You can read the example in the last part of my answer. on logout you can use `localStroage.clear()` to remove all stored items in `localStorage`.

Comment: Is localStroage  store value can acess multiple tab?

Comment: @asasasaa Yes, it is.